# calling php json service file using angular js ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am working on angular js and i need ot call a php service file which returns data in json format,am unable to make an ajax reques from angular js well if i place the data(json)in local its working fine

```
var test = angular.module('TestService', []);

test.factory('TestService', function($http){

            return{

                  getTheTest:function(callback){


             $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                   // url: "https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Super%20Hero",
                    url: 'http://www.domain.com/alumni/wsQuestions.php?courseId=1&modeId=1',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    processData: true,
                    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert('Success :'+JSON.stringify(data));
                    console.log('Success :' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) +"\n"+ "response: "+ JSON.stringify(data));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                  alert('Error :' +xhr.responseText);
                    console.log('error'+ JSON.stringify(xhr));
                    }
                    });



             }


             }
});
```

Comment: does the server which contains the php server run on a different domain which is not CORS enabled?

Comment: yes,service written in this domain are used by many applications,facing a problem with the ajax call using angular

Comment: can you provide the error message of the request from the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the built-in AngularJS $http service. Official documentation, with examples:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$http

Remember to inject $http into your service or controller.